# building raptor RDF from Source on OSX

Tags: rdf, redland, autogen

I am trying to build the Raptor RDF Syntax Library.

I can successfully install it using homebrew but would like to build from source instead.

However,

```
LIBTOOLIZE=/usr/bin/glibtoolize ./autogen.sh 
autogen.sh: Looking for programs: automake aclocal autoconf autoheader libtoolize gtkdocize
autogen.sh: automake program 'automake' V 011200 (min 011102) in /usr/bin
autogen.sh: aclocal program 'aclocal' V 011200 (min 011102) in /usr/bin
autogen.sh: autoconf program 'autoconf' V 026900 (min 026200) in /usr/local/bin
autogen.sh: autoheader program 'autoheader' V 026900 (min 026200) in /usr/local/bin
autogen.sh: libtoolize program '/usr/bin/glibtoolize' V 020210 (min 020200) in environment
autogen.sh: gtkdocize program '' V 0 (min 010300) in 
autogen.sh: ERROR: You must have `gtkdocize' installed to compile this package.
     (version 010300 or newer is required)
```

gtkdocize seems to be a Linux program though. How do I get around this?

Thanks, and apologies for the rather noobish question.

Answer (score 3):

You should build it from a released tarball since that way you don't have to deal with the autotools suite.  It's also a tested and supported tarball.   The latest is always linked from the [Raptor Home Page](http://librdf.org/raptor/)

However, if you want to do the autotools route you will need things like gtkdocize.  It can be found in the gtk-doc-tools package (Debian), gtk-doc (Redhat) and gtk-doc (homebrew on OSX)

Comment: Could you please elaborate what is meant by "gtk-doc (homebrew on OSX)". My *./autogen.sh* currently fails for librdf because *gtkdocize* is absent. I've tried compiling it from [sources](http://www.gtk.org/gtk-doc/download.php), but this leads to several other (apparently hard-to-resolve) [dependencies](http://www.gtk.org/gtk-doc/requirements.php). Isn't there a precompiled distribution of gtk-doc (or even librdf) for OS X (still 10.7.5 in my case) available somewhere and what package management software would give access to it? Thx much.

Comment: the utility 'gtkdocize' is part of the GTK Doc Tools software package.  The package name varies and if you use OSX Homebrew, the package you need is `gtk-doc`.  So you need to `brew install gtk-doc` and then `gtkdocize` will be installed.